# SQL Server 2005: Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, ssms-2005

I have to filter a column called **[Order]** (data type = **decimal(3,1)**) in my final view for **1.0**.

List of unique values for **[Order]** are:

- 1.0
- 2.0
- 3.0
- 4.0
- 5.0
- 7.0
- 8.0
- 9.0
- 11.0
- 12.0
- 13.0

My SQL Statement is as follows:

```
SELECT
        [Order]
FROM
        [dbo].[vwCoreData_AllOtherCats]
WHERE
        [MEDate] = '2/29/2008'
    and [Order] = 1
--  and [Order] = 1.0
--  and [Order] = cast(1 as decimal(3,1))
--  and [Order] = cast(1.0 as decimal(3,1))
```

The commented-out lines shows the different methods I've tried.  All 4 ways results in the same error message:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>
> Arithmetic overflow error int to data type numeric

Anyone know what is going on here?

Thanks for any help anyone can provide,

CTB

Comment: which MEDate type is?

Comment: MEDate data type = smalldatetime.

MEDate shouldn't be an issue though.  If I comment out all **[Order]** filters and filter strictly on MEDate, query runs fine.

It is when I try to filter **[Order] = 1** is when it blows up.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI: **[Order]** is not coming directly from the table as a **decimal(3,1)**, there are several views involved above this one. **[Order]** is stored as **tinyint** in the table. In the view directly above this one, **[Order]** is converted to **decimal(3,1)** using **CAST([Order] AS decimal(3 , 1))**.

Comment: Try casting the other side, not you comparator. CAST([Order] as Numeric(3,1)) = 1. One cannot overflow 1. But a goofy value in Order could. Views, especially views on views get weird... try an exec sp_refreshview - just because a value is moving through them as expect doesn't mean the column definition is still as expected.